# Transformer input voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, transformer

i have a transformer with 0V and 220V(neutral to line voltage) in the primary side. I want to know if it is possible to use a 220V single phase(line to line voltage) as input in the primary side? Thanks!

Comment: As long as the relative voltage isn't exceeded you'll be fine. So if the line to line voltages phaserly add to 220VAC, you are fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the input voltage matches your line - neutral or line - line voltage it will be fine.

Just be careful that if you require isolation that it is an isolating transformer with no connection between the primary and secondary. Some transformers are auto-transformers with shared primary and secondary windings. These do not provide isolation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOEoIc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1 and 2. Isolating and non-isolating transformers.*

Comment: i dont know if this transformer is an isolating or non isolating. It has multiple output(two output voltage). The primary is 0V-220Vac. The secondary is 110Vac and 220Vac according to the label on it.

Comment: Just bell or multimeter continuity check between primary and secondary. Beep = non-isolating. No-beep = isolating (provided your beeper is working.)